# Grounded Conductors and Charge

Tags: electrostatics, conductors, insulators

Not HW, just something that popped up in my mind during a shower XD

Consider a configuration consisting of an insulator that has been charged negatively by friction, and a conductor placed nearby. Obviously, the insulator will induce charges on the surface of the conductor, positive charges accumulating on the side facing the insulator's charged surface, and negative charges on the other "hidden" side.

Suppose I now ground the conductor, such that excess negative charges are drained onto the ground. The conductor now has a positive charge, but is also grounded. The conductor has been grounded, but has a net positive charge.

Since the conductor has been grounded, it follows that it has zero potential. However, this doesn't make sense. Just by looking at the figure one easily sees that the line integral is not zero. If we model the insulator and conductor to be point charges, then we have a dipole. How can a dipole have 0 potential?Is the positively charged conductor actually grounded?

EDIT: I think I may have figured it out. We know that this conductor's surface must be an equipotential. Therefore, if one can prove that at one point on the conductor's surface, V=0, (for example along a path that is always perpendicular to the E-field), then it follows that the entire surface must be at V=0.

Does this reasoning make sense? Or are there any fallacies?